# Charting with ASP.Net MVC 3 and Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC 3 website that I am integrating the Microsoft charting into.  The section I want to add this to is segregated into it's own area of the website.  I have the charting working except for the paths to ChartImg.axd which are what render the image because it is being called from the area all of the resource calls have that path tacked on.  Example:

```
/area/controller/ChartImg.axd
```

This does not work as it is trying to call the resource relatively.

If I change the URL so that the ChartImg.axd is in the root it displays the chart, so I know they are being made.  I would prefer not to save these images as they are being updated frequently, but if I have to do that then I will.

Comment: Have you looked into the new ChartHelper in mvc 3? It's a very simple wrapper around the MSChart control, but if it does what you need it's much easier to work with in MVC.

Comment: You may want to post your solution as an answer and accept it, so it doesn't show in the unanswered listing. (There's no reputation gain or loss.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ignore routes that are required so that the area does not try to alter the url for ChartImg. Once these are added to the RegisterArea function inside of the area the paths to the charts is correctly displayed.

```
context.Routes.Ignore("{controller}/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
context.Routes.Ignore("{controller}/{action}/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```